# wrong output in finding time difference between two unix utc time in python

Tags: python, datetime

I am receiving a request message from a service which has a 'time' field with values like `1550556848042`. Example - `{'object': 'page', 'entry': [{'id': '756686684', 'time': 1550556848042,....}]}`

The time in above looks like a Unix format time in UTC.Now what I want to do is check if the `time` in above is 2 minutes ago from current time in UTC then print the message that it is `more than 2 minutes ago` else print `less than 2 minutes ago`.

I wrote this code to find the time difference but this seems to be not returning the current time difference:

```
import datetime as datetime
import time

#data is the request json as in example above
message_time = data['entry'][0]['time']

message_current_utc_unix_time = int(time.time())
time_diff = int(message_current_utc_unix_time - message_time)
print('TIME DIFFERENCE BETWEEN MESSAGE TIME AND CURRENT TIME = {}'.format(time_diff))
```

Above code returns `time_diff` in `negative` and thus I am unable to figure out the correct syntax. How can I find whether the `time` value in my request json is more than 2 minutes ago than current UTC time?

Comment: the time stamp is not unix timestamp i guess, currently the unix timestamp is only 10 digits followed by decimal points e.g., `1550556848.042`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
data = {
    'object': 'page', 'entry': [{'id': '756686684', 'time': 1550556848.042, }]
}
if (time.time() - data['entry'][0]['time']) < (2 * 60):
    print('less than 2 minutes ago')
else:
    print('more than 2 minutes ago')
```

Answer (score 0):

The number does *not* look like seconds since the epoch. It looks very much since *milliseconds* since the epoch. You want

```
import datetime
import time

#data is the request json as in example above
message_time = data['entry'][0]['time'] / 1000   # notice divisor

message_current_utc_unix_time = int(time.time())
time_diff = int(message_current_utc_unix_time - message_time)
print('Time difference without shouting = {}'.format(time_diff))
```